# Syntax - PHP substring

Tags: php, substring

I have problems placing a sub-string in the statement below.

My wish is to cut the output after 19 positions but I am struggling with the syntax.

Your help is much appreciated! - thanks

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute ($_product,$_product->getName(),'name')?>
```

Comment: `echo substr($string, 0, 19);`

Comment: what's your string and sample output of sub-string function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo substr($_helper->productAttribute ($_product,$_product->getName(),'name'), 0, 19); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
<?php 
 $name = $_helper->productAttribute ($_product,$_product->getName(),'name');
  echo substr($name,0,19);
 ?>
```

For more see here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

Comment: I don't mind..but if you are new to stack ..then always use concept of first right first accept.

Comment: indeed and i was first :) i posted the solution in a comment to his question then i waited for feedback

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look substr function in php. Following link might be helpful
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php